# How to get video length using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, codeigniter-3

I am getting the duration of video using following code,

```
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){            
    $time = exec("{$ffmpeg} -i $path 2>&1 | findstr Duration"); 

    echo $time;
    exit;

    $duration = explode(":", $time);                
    $seconds = ($duration[0] * 3600) + ($duration[1] * 60) + round($duration[2]);   
    $minutes = $seconds/60;
    $real_minutes = floor($minutes);
    $real_seconds = round(($minutes-$real_minutes)*60);
    $length = $real_minutes.':'.$real_seconds;
}
```

`$time` shows the output like `Duration: 00:00:06.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 350 kb/s` but `$duration` shows only like `Array` ans `$length` shows 0:0 only for all videos. So how can i get video length please help me.

Comment: Since `$duration` contains the result of `explode()`, it _should_ be an array. Do a `var_dump($duration)` and check what it contains.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  var_dump($duration) shows like this              
 array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "  Duration"
  [1]=>
  string(3) " 00"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "06.52, start"
  [4]=>
  string(18) " 0.000000, bitrate"
  [5]=>
  string(9) " 350 kb/s"
}

Comment: Thanks this question helped me to figure out how to get ffmpeg to print the duration in the first place. That has hard to track down.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get duration. Pass the absolute path of the file as an argument:

```
 public static function getDuration($filePath)
{
    exec('ffmpeg -i'." '$filePath' 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,",$O,$S);
    if(!empty($O[0]))
    {
        return $O[0];
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Make sure your $filePath is absolute

Answer (score 0):

If you have ffmpeg.exe or installed use this function because it is working very nice for me, i think that should be the same to you

```
function getDuration($file){
  $dur = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$file." 2>&1");
  if(preg_match("/: Invalid /", $dur)){
     return false;
  }
  preg_match("/Duration: (.{2}):(.{2}):(.{2})/", $dur, $duration);
  if(!isset($duration[1])){
     return false;
  }
  return $duration[1].":".$duration[2].":".$duration[3];
}
```

## Demo

echo getDuration($input); #input is the path of the file to get duration